# No puedo detectar siempre la última fecha en python

Tags: python

tengo un codigo creado en python y lo necesito para detectar siempre la ultima fecha del json de la api de fortnite, como podria hacerlo? aqui les dejo mi codigo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
response = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")



fecha = isoparse(response.json()['data'][0]['shopHistory']).timestamp()

timestamp = fecha


date1 =  parser.parse(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) 
date2 = datetime.now()
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
r.months + (12*r.years)


print(max(r.days))
```

Lo hice con un "max" pero no me aparece el resultado

Debo de contar los días transcurridos desde la última fecha hasta la actual Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer esto desde mi código me tira error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la `última fecha` es la fecha más cerca a la fecha actual del presente?

Comment: Sí, es la mas cerca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes convertir las fechas en un numero (en tiempo unix) y usar la función max para que te devuelva el número mayor y luego conviertes ese número en una fecha nuevamente

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime
response = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")


json_date= response.json()
timestamps  = [datetime.strptime(fecha, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").timestamp()  for fecha in json_date['data'][0]['shopHistory']]
timestamp= max(timestamps)

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp), "La fecha más cercana a la fecha actual")

print((datetime.now()- datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)).days, "Días transcurridos")
```

Resultado

```bash
2022-11-01T00:00:00 La fecha más cercana a la fecha actual
14 Días transcurridos
```

Answer (score 1):

as intentado algo como esto?

```
import requests
import re

response = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")


fechas = response.json()['data'][0]['shopHistory']
print(fechas)
## usamos una expresion regular para remplazar las letras
## luego strip para eliminar los espacios al final 
fechas = [ re.sub(r"[TZ]"," ",x).strip() for x in fechas ]
# y ya la tenemos formateada a gusto
print( fechas )
```

resultado:

```
['2021-10-16 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-17 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-18 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-19 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-20 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-21 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-22 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-23 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-30 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-31 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-10 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-11 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-12 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-13 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-14 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-15 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-16 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-30 00:00:00',
 '2022-10-31 00:00:00',
 '2022-11-01 00:00:00']
```

Comment: asi si funciona, pero tengo que contar los dias desde la ultima fecha hasta la de ahora

Comment: como desde la ultima fecha? cual seria la ultima fecha???

Comment: 2022-11-01T00:00:00Z  y contando la de hoy 17-11-2022